# Are resource questions about study documentation schemes on topic?

Tags: discussion

Question about [on-topicness](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topicness)

So I'm looking for an **ontology** (RDF/OWL) of potential conflicts of interest in medical research; and thought MedScience might be the most appropriate SE (but not sure). While it's research-related, it could already be a bit too programming-adjacent, and it's a find-me-the-right-[resource question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/997/give-me-a-resource-questions)
of sorts.

**Motivation:**
Notably my origin interest is about a field only peripherally related to the medical realm, namely public health and tobacco control (→in parts faux public health).  Albeit with overlap in research methodologies and study formats.  And often unacknowledged COIs (classification varies wildly between journals) I'd think are applicable across the board - including the very [philosophical debate](https://doi.org/10.1177/0956797613511824) about how much disclosure is desirable.  And I'm assuming there's similar overlap with potential domain priors or implicit biases in other clinical explorations; if any such ontology were to cover those as well.

**Scope::**
So what I'm hoping to get out of the question is a reference relating to the [OBO foundries'](https://obofoundry.org/), or from the [OLS thingy](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies). I've seen traces of e.g. [`financial-`](https://addictovocab.org/ADDICTO:0000514) or `personal-stake` denominations scattered elsewhere. But I'd be surprised if there wasn't a compendium ontology already. Just can't pinpoint it myself. Kinda shocked that it's such a vast topic nowadays.

Yet what I'm not looking forward is another flowtext paper, or shallow enumerations (da journals).

So, would this be on-topic here? Or perhaps Academia.SE be a better bet? (Might be even more fringe there.)

Comment: This comment makes me suspect you aren't very familiar with Medical Sciences.SE: `While it's research-related, it could already be a bit too programming-centered`. It's not programming-centered at all. Programming questions are entirely off topic.

Comment: Hence the caveat. Albeit I should clarify, wouldn't be an actual programming question here of course. Just topical to point out RDF/OWL as probable/desired outcome. (Implying the secondary use.)

Comment: I wouldn't expect physicians and other medical professionals to know acronyms like RDF and OWL.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the crux here. Even "ontology" or "vocabulary" might already be too fringe a research topic. Wasn't sure if the biomed dictionaries would ring anyones bell. And if such a question would end up a tumbleweed, it's probably off-topic (specifically for a beta site).

Comment: Ignore my first comment. I guess I misinterpreted "it's" in the sentence I quoted to refer to this group rather than the subject matter. But either way I don't think it's on topic here.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks! If it's already beyond the usual question scope and (more importanly) general interest, then I'll see if it'll fit elsewhere. (Not sure, perhaps Academia given the self-disclosure aspects.)

Comment: I think Academia is your best bet. Just post this question in their meta and find out.